# Forcing safari to expand its filter region to avoid grid-like rendering

Tags: html, css, svg, safari

Been learning a lot from this forum and up until this point, been able to find solution to all of my amateurish coding problems by reading and searching here. Might be Ive misjudged the problem, but this time Im well and truly stuck.

Ive tried to introduce an effect to front page/"bookcover" part of my site, with an keyframed clip-path to animate a polygon mask around the photo in question. Only CSS here and it works fine across platforms. All fine 'til this point.

Trouble arises: I tried rounding off the corners by means of svg filter, many of you know this trinity - 1. gaussian, 2. colormatrix then, 3. composite.

Ive cross-browser tested this and found Safari to be the only platform struggling with rendering the animation correctly. First of all it seems to be a HUGE power-drain on Safari, lagging while buffering the 10-sec animation. Secondly, and I suspect this is partly why Safari is having such a hard time, my blobby mask-shape is divided into what seems like a grid. This forces Safari to apply the effect more times, relative to how many grid-squares the shape is divided into.

So my main question is, any workarounds here? Would it be a viable solution to tell Safari to stop slicing my shape and how would one go about that?

Attached two screenshots, one from Safari with the mentioned effect and second from Chrome.

This is the filter-code, accessed in CSS by filter: url(#round):

```
<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<defs>
<filter id="round" x="-50%" width="200%" y="-50%" height="200%" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">    
<feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="25" result="blur" />
<feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values=  "1 0 0 0 0  
                                                                                        0 1 0 0 0
                                                                                        0 0 1 0 0
                                                                                        0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
<feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
</filter>
</defs>
</svg>
```

[Safari, three vertical sections somehow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCLEn.png)

[Chrome, no problem, same with Opera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei9us.jpg)

Ive noticed a lot of people experiencing unintentional results with these svg-effects applied to CSS, so maybe this way is just too unstable and hacky way of achieving the animated mask with rounded corners that I want.

Comment: There are multiple ways to write the "blob" effect, and compatibility might differ between browsers. See my [blog post](https://browser-unplugged.net/blog/gooeybugs.en.html) about it. It contains a tool to spell out different variants of the filter code.

Comment: @ccprog Thank you. I read that blogpost before submitting this, as the solutions you promote hits quite close to what I want, but not right there. As of now I have given up on this as I can see no way of getting Safari to behave like the others. Thank you though, for taking the time